# Regex to match all Firefox version greater than X

Tags: regex, expression

I was looking for a way to match a regex to the user agent of the Firefox.

example : `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0`

And I would like it to match "all versions above 111" in this case.

Would appreciate some help , thanks in advance.

I tried things like `(10\d|1[1-9]\d|[2-9]\d{2})` but this is not the solution I am looking for since this should allow 100 to 999

Comment: Why did you try that? You must have had a plan to start your regex with `10`. What was it? Or did you copy this regex from somewhere...

Comment: If you're dealing with user agents, it is likely that you have access to JavaScript. If that's the case, extract the version number out, then test it by JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want the match the 111.0 and assuming that the decimal part is only numeric, you can use a capture group:

```
\b(?:Firefox|FxiOS)\/((?:\b11[1-9]|1[2-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})(?:\.\d+)+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:Firefox|FxiOS)` Match either Firefox or FxiOS (or add more alternatives)
- `\/` Match `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

    - `\b11[1-9]|1[2-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,}` Match from 111 and up
  - `)` Close the non capture group
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?:\.\d+)+)` Match 1+ times `.` and 1+ digits
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3xLX0j/1) with some variations (note that there might be more)

If you also want to match versions with a format like `10.0a4` then you can change the pattern to:

```
\b(?:Firefox|FxiOS)\/((?:\b11[1-9]|1[2-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d{3,})(?:\.[^\W_]+)+)
```